# How to write function in Spark column so a each field in the column increment the value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It's not about unique id so I don't mean to use the increase unique number api, but try to resolve it by customized query

consider given value like 30, now current dataframe `df` needs to add a new column called `hop_number` so each field in the column from top to bottom will increment by 2 starts from 30, so that

```
with 2 parameters
x -> start number, here is 30
y -> like step or offset, here is 2

   hop_number
---------------
      30
      32
      34
      36
      38
      40
    ......
```

I know in RDD we can use a `map` to handle the job, but how to do the same in dataframe with minimal cost?

```
df.column("hop_number", 30 + map(x => x + 2)) // pseudo code
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need some sort condition on the dataframe first, because otherwise it would be random. And then you can have a look at window functions probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


scala> val x = lit(30)
x: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = 30

scala> val y = lit(2)
y: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = 2

scala> df.withColumn("hop_number",(x + (row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1)))-1) * y)).show(false)

+----------+
|hop_number|
+----------+
|30        |
|32        |
|34        |
|36        |
|38        |
+----------+
```

Comment: thanks, I try the code in spark-shell (spark 2.3) but the 3rd command returned `error: not found: value Window`, I added `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.window` and also I think it is not required in spark-shell but still got the same error

Comment: my bad, I forgot to inculde import statements.. now i have added. please check if it works .. upvote or accept .. :)

Comment: np, I imported the wrong package and now it works. Thanks a lot for the follow up

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a grouping and ordering column, you can use the window function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,1,14),(1,2,4),(1,3,10),(2,1,90),(7,2,30),(2,3,11)],schema=['group','order','value'])
w=Window.partitionBy('group').orderBy('order')
tst_hop= tst.withColumn("temp",F.sum(F.lit(2)).over(w)).withColumn("hop_number",F.col('temp')+28)
```

The results:

```
tst_hop.show()
+-----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|group|order|value|temp|hop_number|
+-----+-----+-----+----+----------+
|    1|    1|   14|   2|        30|
|    1|    2|    4|   4|        32|
|    1|    3|   10|   6|        34|
|    2|    1|   90|   2|        30|
|    2|    3|   11|   4|        32|
|    7|    2|   30|   2|        30|
+-----+-----+-----+----+----------+
```

If you need a different approach, please provide a sample data of the dataframe.